# Can Trusted computing/TPM defeat crack attempts?

Tags: hardware, cryptography, software-security

I read some things about trusted computing platforms (TPM) and its applications in the past.

AFAIK, its applications include such things as countering software reverse engineering/crack and cheating in multiplayer games. And nowadays, it seems that most systems (including most PCs) have trusted computing capabilities or TPM chips.

I want to know how widespread are TC applications at the moment and how successful they were (or can be if implemented/used properly - I mean without any human mistakes) in achieving their goals.

And, can TC be a definitive end to reverse engineering/crack (at least in some cases), and if not, why?

It seems to me that TC has great capabilities and can create strong protection against software manipulation, because I am somewhat informed in cryptography and I know it uses modern and strong cryptographic algorithms/protocols ... that breaking them is almost infeasible if implemented properly (free of human mistakes). But, on the other hand, I don't know why its use is not widespread yet (apparently) and almost all software are cracked everyday (Although I have some guesses myself, like extra complexity and cost required to implement such software, also the cryptography knowledge/expertise required that almost no ordinary programmer has).

So, I decided to ask this question from you here.

**PS**: Maybe I should have posted this question in crypto or security StackExchange sites. IDK for sure, but probably will try them if I don't get enough info here.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is a definitive answer to this.

For example, anyone with physical access to the system can do a whole manner of things that TPM may not be able to prevent.

For example, the TPM itself could be reverse engineered: http://gcn.com/articles/2010/02/02/black-hat-chip-crack-020210.aspx?m=1

Then you have timing attacks and other side channels.

And as you say yourself, cost and complexity: this is well summed up by Andrew 'Bunnie' Huang in 'Hacking the Xbox' (pg. 203, http://www.nostarch.com/xboxfree)

> In the consumer electronics industry, one can either ship a perfect
>   product, or one can make money. Products that don't make money are
>   quickly cancelled. Thus, it is very rare to find a consumer product that is
>   technically perfect in all respects. As a result, the only practical way to
>   guarantee the security of consumer electronics system as complex as
>   Palladium is to throw it into the wild, and let the hackers have their way
>   with it for many years until all of the big security holes have been
>   discovered and plugged.
>
> On the other hand, the TCPA's TPM is a device created to solve a certain
>   set of problems that is smaller in scope than Palladium's. Thus, the TPM
>   is not as exciting from a market perspective, but it may be more practical
>   and serviceable for its intended purpose. Both the TPM and Palladium
>   are weak to hardware attacks, but the TPM doesn't attempt to extend
>   security requirements as far into third-party system design territory. The
>   TPM is primarily a secured key management module that can detect most
>   modifications and intrusions to the host system. The software layers built
>   on top of this substrate do the rest of the heavy lifting, caveat emptor.